# Transparency/Alpha and MKOverlayView issue

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, alpha, mkoverlay

Having wrestled with many problems with MKOverlayViews and MKMapKit I find myself with one more.  I'm using an MKOverlayPathView subclass to draw a singular large overlay on the screen (it covers London at the moment).  Within that overlay are lots of coloured squares for arguments sake:

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    int size = 0;
    min = 0;
    max = 0;
    CGFloat alpha = 0.4f;
    int recursionLevel = 4;
    QuadNodeOverlay *quadNodeOverlay = (QuadNodeOverlay *)self.overlay;

    Cluster *clusters = quadtree_clusters(quadNodeOverlay.quadTree, recursionLevel, &size);

    if (clusteringMethod == 1) {
        /* Draw paths/squares */
        CGPathRef *paths = [self createPaths:clusters size:size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            CGPathRef path = paths[i];
            Cluster cluster = clusters[i];
            CGContextBeginPath(context);
            CGContextAddPath(context, path);
            //CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, colors[cluster.depth]);
            CGColorRef gradientColor = [self newColor:cluster.count];
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, gradientColor);
            CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
            CGColorRelease(gradientColor);
            CGPathRelease(path);
        }

        free(paths);
    } else if (clusteringMethod == 2) {
       // CUT
    }

    [self setAlpha:alpha];
}
```

The above code is incomplete but provides a solid basis for the question.  The code works fine and performs admirable fast regardless of the number of squares I want to draw.  The problem I have is below a certain point I'm not drawing this overlay; I manage this in the view controller containing the map:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)map regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.annotations = [locationServer itemsForMapRegion:map.region withMapView:map maxCount:100];
    NSLog(@"There are like %d cards dude.",[self.annotations count]);
    if ( [self.annotations count] > 40) {
        [mapView removeAnnotations:annotations];
        // Cluster
        if (![[mapView overlays] containsObject:quadClusters]) {
            [mapView addOverlay:quadClusters];
        }
    } else {
        // Don't
        [mapView removeOverlay:quadClusters];

        // Add pins.
        [mapView removeAnnotations:annotations];
        [mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
    }
}
```

Again this code works fine my purposes right now.  The problem is when I zoom in to a level where the clusters are not displayed but the individual annotations are when I zoom back out a chuck of the overlay is rendered without transparency.  Vis:

[image: Overlay Cluster partially loses transparency/alpha]

As a foot note.  Removing the setAlpha from the overlay and modifying the code that draws the squares to read:

```
        CGColorRef gradientColor = [self newColor:cluster.count];
        CGColorRef alphaGradientColor = CGColorCreateCopyWithAlpha(gradientColor, alpha);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, alphaGradientColor);
```

resolves the issue, however surely applying the alpha channel to the overlay as a whole is more efficient.

Comment: please post solution if available.

Comment: This is going back a bit, I'll try and dig out what I ended up with and post it as an answer.  Might take me a day or two though.